# Laptop - Dell - Windows 11 - Touch

Tags: laptop, keyboard

My laptops bezel is stuck to the upper part of the keyboard; I don’t know if I should force it because I see three golden circles and I’m scared they are essential.

What should I do?

[image: here are the three circles and the glued/stuck bezel]

The screen still turns on and from what I can see, it’s fine.

Answer (score 0):

You should most definitely get the machine serviced.  What you show in the photo is not good, not correct, and may need a new display to fix the issue.

Unless you are very mechanically adept, this is not a do-it-yourself job.

Since it is running Windows 11, it is reasonably new. Think about the economics of repair or replacement with a new machine.